# Cloud composer authentication of other google cloud service accounts

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-search-console

Scientist out of depth trying to do some data engineering.

I'm currently trying to turn my manually executed local python scripts that generate local csv files into cloud composer scheduled API calls resulting in data stored to google cloud storage and incorporated into bigquery tables.

If my google account for cloud composer is triggering all of these steps: google search console API (currently credentials are serialized using searchconsole library & I have .json and .dat files), cloud storage and bigquery, would I be able to avoid authentication steps because the whole thing is controlled by the same google account?

Or do I still need to authenticate and list scopes as webmaster & bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup authentication usins Service Account. When you run Cloud Composer, it uses a Service Account (which you choose when you create the Cloud Composer Instance). All your workloads run with this Service Account and in order to access the different GCP service, you need to make sure that service account has appropriate access to those services. It can even impersonate user accounts if needed and if you set it up properly.

All details and step-by-step instructions can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/authentication